# Magento Categories not working

Tags: magento-1.9, category, database, backend, sql

I had attempted to import categories into my magento using SQL, but looks like it hasn't worked. In manage categories section it looks like this:

[image]

The numbers suggest correct product linking but other than that broken, clicking the expand button also does nothing.

**UPDATE:   **

I have got the categories, and sub-categories to display. But the products although correctly showing in the count next to the categories, they are not appearing when I click on the actual category and got to the category products tab:

[image]

Comment: Check category is active or not

Comment: the categories seem malfunctioned. They should be set to active, and the name of the categories isn't even showing.

Comment: I don't know what is the exact problem try to reindex once and clear cache / Session

Comment: @Kothari attempted reindex, get trouble in that the category flat data index wont reindex. Looking at the exceptions.log  get: Exception message: Notice: Undefined offset: 67  in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php on line 833

Comment: Check that error in google

Comment: @Kothari I have managed to get the categories displaying correctly. Just the products are not showing (see update of question)

Comment: did you reindex catalog product

Comment: @Kothari yes but I believe reindex does not seem to be working properly now

Comment: i think its prob of reindex

Comment: @Kothari yes my reindexing seems to be broken now. Any pointers how I could debug the cause ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by ensuring the eav attributes references were correct. Both installations had referenced attributes in different rows, thus the references needed updating in the category tables.